# Page tree collapses when editor deletes page

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

When I delete a page in the page tree with an **admin user**, the page gets deleted. So far, so good.

When I do the same with an **editor user**, the page gets deleted *and* the page tree collapses, so only the root page and the first underlying level are visible.

Is there a setting where I can change this behaviour?

(this is not a fresh TYPO3 installation, I upgraded from v6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After resetting the user preferences (`Maintenance > Reset Backend User Preferences`) the delete process works as expected and the page tree doesn't collapse anymore.